# Is there a CLI framework or library that allows users to search a database using SQL syntax but prevents injection attacks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

We have a database table of systems that our users query extensively.  We currently allow them to access them via CLI:

```
# mycmd --fields "hostname,ipaddress" --sql "osname='linux' \
and numcpus > 2 and domain like '%example.com'"
```

Which simply runs the command:

```
SELECT hostname,ipaddress FROM systems WHERE osname='linux' \
and numcpus > 2 and domain like '%example.com'
```

As you can see, this gives them a lot of flexibility.  It also seems potentially dangerous.

- Potential SQL injection
- Requires knowledge of SQL syntax

We'd like to re-write this command so that it prevents injection but still gives users the same flexibility.

Is there a framework that can help support this?

Or would it be terrible to simply leave the command as-is but simply give it read-only DB access?

Comment: AFAIK, theres no such thing, because there's no pre-defined syntax distinction between "user written SQL" and "an injection attack". For instance, a query that returns every user and their home phone number might be legit, or it might be an attack, it depends on the application, the user and the context.  You have to make that distinction.

Comment: What will happen if user types `mycmd --fields "hostname,ipaddress" --sql "osname='linux' \
and numcpus > 2; SELECT GETDATE()";`

Comment: I'm pretty much just looking for "SELECT A WHERE B" so the users can put any fields in A and (almost) any conditional logic in B (based on simple comparators).

Comment: Then the way to handle that is with Schema security and stored procedure(s).

Comment: Could you explain what stored procedures would be for?